# Invalid (or missing) template file (path must be workspace-relative, or absolute):

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I'm trying to debug a python function locally with VSC and I receive the following error message:

Invalid (or missing) template file (path must be workspace-relative, or absolute): /Volumes/ExtremeSSD/Amazon/SalesForce/amazon-connect-salesforce-lambda/sam-app/lambda_functions

The launch.json is set as follows:

```
 {
      "type": "aws-sam",
      "request": "direct-invoke",
      "name": "lambda_functions:sfInvokeAPI",
      "invokeTarget": {
        "target": "template",
        "templatePath": "/Volumes/ExtremeSSD/Amazon/SalesForce/amazon-connect-salesforce-lambda/sam-app/lambda_functions",
        "logicalId": "sfInvokeAPI"
      },
```

I cannot understand why is VSC complaining if I have set the correct path. Any hints?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to close and open VSC?